# CENTOS - Linux - Make - Makefile (Get User Input not working)

Tags: makefile, centos, gnu-make

For one of my projects I am using Makefile to carry out some tasks. But for some reason the system is not capturing my input or I might doing something wrong. Here is my code:

```
@read -e -p "Please enter email-addresses: " -i "user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com" EMAIL_ADDRESSES
@echo $EMAIL_ADDRESSES;
@echo $$EMAIL_ADDRESSES;
@echo ${EMAIL_ADDRESSES};
@echo $${EMAIL_ADDRESSES};
```

But here is my output:

```
MAIL_ADDRESSES
[Blank]
[Blank]
[Blank]
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make always run its recipes in `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`.  Some of the capabilities you're using here for `read` are specific to Bash and are not available in standard POSIX shells.

Second, make runs every individual line in a recipe in a different shell.  So any shell variables you set in one line are lost when the shell exits and are not available in the next line.  If you want to preserve them you need to put the entire script on a single (logical) line, like this:

```
@printf 'Please enter email-addresses: '; \
    read EMAIL_ADDRESSES; \
    echo $$EMAIL_ADDRESSES
```

If you really want to use Bash features you should probably invoke it directly.

Lastly, it's generally a bad idea to use standard input from a makefile.  If someone ever wanted to run your makefile with parallel jobs enabled then all but one command will not have any standard input (it will be redirected from `/dev/null`).  It's better to ask the user to provide the value on the command line as a make variable assignment.